# getImage method always return placeholder image - Magento2.1.7EE

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, magento-2.1.7, magento2-enterprise

One of my extension using the below code to retrieve product image in **listing page**.

```
$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
```

**getImage()** method presents in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php`

```
public function getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes = [])
{
    return $this->imageBuilder->setProduct($product)
        ->setImageId($imageId)
        ->setAttributes($attributes)
        ->create();
}
```

But the above one always return placeholder image instead of product image.

**Note** : We have all the product images in `pub/media/catalog/product/cache` (**bin/magento catalog:images:resize**) but somehow above one always return placeholder.

any ideas? how to debug? how to find the actual image URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add Module_Vendor/Module_Name/etc/view.xml with $imageId you use. E.g. $imageId = 'product_thumbnail_image':

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="product_thumbnail_image" type="thumbnail">
            <width>75</width>
            <height>75</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
```